klein-four poset?
While tinkering with what I believe to be a four-valued logic system, I arrived upon these operations. They're commutative, and the heart one seems to just be addition on the Klein four-group, while the club one seems to be some sort of infimum.

I have heard that tropical geometry uses max and addition instead of addition and multiplication. Is what I have above the tropical semiring of some finite ring?

It's even simpler than that, the club is the multiplication in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, where $\top=(1,1)$, $\perp = 0$, and the two other are $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ in whichever order you want.
So you almost just have the ring $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ with your two operations, except that $0$ and $1$ are exchanged in the two laws. It can also be reformulated as saying that this is $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}, +, \ast)$ where
$$(x\ast y) + 1 = (x+1)\cdot (y+1).$$

Hello. I haven't fully checked the above tables, but isn't the club operation idempotent, while your $\ast$ operation isn't? Did you mean $(x + y) \cdot (y + 1) - 1$? Sorry if I'm being silly!

You are absolutely right, what I meant is that $x\mapsto x+1$ transports the club operation to the product, but of course I forgot to apply it on both sides!
